# C# event subscriber queuing

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

What happens if an event is raised faster than it is consumed by the subscriber?
Is the event handler started on a new "thread" every time the event is raised.
Or do the events get queued and the handler for the next event gets called only when the one for the previous event is finished execution?

Comment: Unless you run the consumer in a different thread, it will run on the same thread as the invoker, so the invoker won't be able to trigger another event until the consumer has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to test. Here's a program I set up to show what happens:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Invoker invoker = new Invoker();
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(invoker);
        invoker.RunEvents();
    }
}

class Invoker
{
    public delegate void SomeEventHandler();

    public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;

    public void RunEvents()
    {
        while (true)
            SomeEvent.Invoke();
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(Invoker invoker)
    {
        invoker.SomeEvent += HandleSomeEvent;
    }

    private void HandleSomeEvent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling event");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

What you'll find is that the "Handling event" message is only output to console once every 500ms even though the Invoker() is trying to trigger the event as rapidly as possible.

This is because the event handler is running on the same thread as the invoker. There's no queueing up or starting a new thread. The invoker simply can't invoke the event more quickly than the handler handles the event because they're on the same thread.